# Raw socket for transport layer protocol

Tags: sockets, c++

What I want to do is make my own transport layer protocol in C++. I can't figure out how to create a raw socket that that automatically resolves IP headers, and leaves it up to me to set the payload.

I managed to receive packets on the server using

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP))
```

but didn't manage to create a client that can send data to the server. (I'm not even sure if the above socket is L2 or L3)

From what I understand from reading about raw sockets, a L3 socket would look like

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, protocol)
```

Thing is, I don't know what to fill in for the protocol, if my intention is to create my own and not to use existing ones. (I have tried many of the iana numbers, including the range 143-252)

So the question is: how to create a socket, server and client sided, on top of the Internet Protocol such that two computers can communicate in an arbitrary protocol (or send data to each other)? In other words, I want to specify the end IP address and a payload and have the socket take care of the IP header.

What I have now:

server.cpp: https://pastebin.com/yLMFLDmJ

client.cpp: https://pastebin.com/LWuNdqPT

Comment: Look at the source code of (just about any implementation of) `ping`.

Comment: By my understanding, if you use `AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, protocol`, `recvfrom()` etc should receive anything with the matching protocol (and send accordingly). Note that you'll get an IP header on receive. What specific problems have you encountered? (e.g. with the protocol numbers)

Comment: Why not using UDP instead? I wonder how well custom, unsupported protocol can behave in internet...

Comment: @sklott the purpose is learning. I know I can use other protocols, but that was not the point

Comment: @Hasturkun I want to create my own protocol, not implement one that already exists, so I can't just choose a protocol number for the `protocol` argument, can I?

Comment: The only difference AFAIK between RAW and UPD is that `protocol` field is set to `UDP` and two port numbers added to packet (4 bytes total), to disambiguate connections of different applications. So I don't see such a difference for learning purposes. But it guarantee that this protocol will work over any and all hardware/software in internet. When you put your own custom protocol there is no guarantee that anything will work at all beside your local network.

Comment: @sklott I was going to make some kind of file transfer protocol and use it with my RaspberryPi. If I don't find a way of doing it lower level, I'll use UDP or TCP, but I've spent the last 3 days trying to figure it out and I don't want to give up yet.

Comment: If it will be used for local transfer only, I think you can use any protocol number except those recognized by system(s) on which you will use it.

Comment: Protocol numbers 253 and 254 are reserved for experimentation and testing, so you can use one of those safely. (i.e. You shouldn't run into anything using one of those two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are searching, here is the solution I found: http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html

In the file tcp4.c on the above mentioned page, there is a client implementation using a raw socket. The code adds both IP and TCP headers, but you can simply remove the lines where the TCP headers are added and replace them with your own protocol. You also need to change this line: `iphdr.ip_p = IPPROTO_TCP` to `iphdr.ip_p = 200` (200 or any number in the range 143-252; see https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) and set the name of the interface you are using, as well as change the addresses.

So here is a stripped down version with the mentioned changes that sends an IP packet only containing IP headers: https://pastebin.com/z2sGmtQd

And here is a very simple server that can receive these packets: https://pastebin.com/jJgZUv5p